# Play video stream on glSurfaceView

Tags: android, video-streaming, client-server, webrtc

I am developing an Android client for a Kurento Node.js server. What I'm trying to do is to play the remote and local stream on a `<org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer>`.
The problem is my code does not work for all types of devices. On a Samsung S7 works fine but on Huawei P9 Lites it shows only a black screen.

```
 package ro.hpm.hypertalk;

    import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.WindowManager;

    import com.google.gson.Gson;
    import com.google.gson.JsonObject;

    import org.json.JSONException;
    import org.json.JSONObject;
    import org.webrtc.DataChannel;
    import org.webrtc.EglBase;
    import org.webrtc.IceCandidate;
    import org.webrtc.MediaStream;
    import org.webrtc.PeerConnection;
    import org.webrtc.RendererCommon;
    import org.webrtc.SessionDescription;
    import org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer;

    import fi.vtt.nubomedia.webrtcpeerandroid.NBMMediaConfiguration;
    import fi.vtt.nubomedia.webrtcpeerandroid.NBMPeerConnection;
    import fi.vtt.nubomedia.webrtcpeerandroid.NBMWebRTCPeer;
    import io.socket.client.Socket;
    import io.socket.emitter.Emitter;

    public class VideoPeer extends AppCompatActivity implements NBMWebRTCPeer.Observer {


        private Socket mSocket;
        public static String userType ="viewer";
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject();
        private final String TAG = "VideoPeer";
        private SurfaceViewRenderer remoteRenderer;
        private SurfaceViewRenderer localRenderer;
        private enum CallState { IDLE, PUBLISHING, PUBLISHED, WAITING_REMOTE_USER, RECEIVING_REMOTE_USER };
        private User user = new User();
        private String mData;
        private CallState callState;
        private NBMMediaConfiguration peerConnectionParameters;
        private NBMWebRTCPeer nbmWebRTCPeer;


        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_video_peer);
            getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);
            remoteRenderer = (SurfaceViewRenderer) findViewById(R.id.remote_renderer);
            remoteRenderer.init(EglBase.create().getEglBaseContext(), null);
            localRenderer = (SurfaceViewRenderer) findViewById(R.id.local_renderer);
            localRenderer.init(EglBase.create().getEglBaseContext(), null);
            callState = CallState.IDLE;

        }

        @Override
        protected void onStart() {
            super.onStart();

            remoteRenderer.setScalingType(RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL);
            localRenderer.setScalingType(RendererCommon.ScalingType.SCALE_ASPECT_FILL);


            try {
                SocketHandler.emitMessage("create or join");
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
            }

            SocketHandler.getmSocket().on("created", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "message back:received ");
                    userType = "presenter";
                    presenter();
                }
            });
            SocketHandler.getmSocket().on("joined", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(Object... args) {
                    System.out.println("I have joined the room:" + user.getRoom());
                    viewer();
                }
            });
    }


        public void presenter(){

            constrains();
            nbmWebRTCPeer = new NBMWebRTCPeer(peerConnectionParameters, this, localRenderer, this);
            nbmWebRTCPeer.registerMasterRenderer(localRenderer);
            nbmWebRTCPeer.initialize();
            callState = CallState.PUBLISHING;

        }

        public void viewer(){

            constrains();
            nbmWebRTCPeer = new NBMWebRTCPeer(peerConnectionParameters, this, localRenderer, this);
            nbmWebRTCPeer.registerMasterRenderer(localRenderer);
            nbmWebRTCPeer.initialize();
            callState = CallState.WAITING_REMOTE_USER;
        }


        public void constrains(){
            peerConnectionParameters = new NBMMediaConfiguration(
                    NBMMediaConfiguration.NBMRendererType.OPENGLES,
                    NBMMediaConfiguration.NBMAudioCodec.OPUS, 0,
                    NBMMediaConfiguration.NBMVideoCodec.VP8, 0,
                    new NBMMediaConfiguration.NBMVideoFormat(352, 288, PixelFormat.RGB_888, 20),
                    NBMMediaConfiguration.NBMCameraPosition.FRONT);
        }


        @Override
        protected void onDestroy(){
            super.onDestroy();

            SocketHandler.getmSocket().disconnect();
            SocketHandler.getmSocket().off("created", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            Log.i(TAG, "Message received");
                            JSONObject data = (JSONObject) args[0];
                            Log.i(TAG, data.toString());
                            Log.i(TAG, new Gson().toJson(data));
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }


        @Override
        public void onInitialize() {
           if(userType.equals("presenter")) {
            nbmWebRTCPeer.generateOffer("local", true);
            }
           else{
                nbmWebRTCPeer.generateOffer("MyRemotePeer", false);
           }
        }



        @Override
        public void onLocalSdpOfferGenerated(final SessionDescription localSdpOffer, NBMPeerConnection connection) {

            Log.i(TAG,"Entered here");


            Log.i(TAG, "sending message");
            if(userType.equals("presenter")) {

                    Log.i(TAG, "Socket Check "+ user.toString());
                SocketHandler.emitMessage("startPresenter");
                Log.i("socket check sdpOffer", SocketHandler.getmSocket().toString());
            } else{
                final JSONObject sdpObjViewer = new JSONObject();
                Constants.userParameters.setUserType("viewer");
                Constants.userParameters.setSdpOffer(localSdpOffer.description);
                SocketHandler.emitMessage("startViewer");
  Constants.userParameters);

            }

            Log.i(TAG, "socket check On create "+ SocketHandler.getmSocket().toString());

            SocketHandler.getmSocket().on("sdpAnswerFromServer-mobile", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onSdpAnswerFromServer listener " + args[0]);
                    JSONObject obj = null;
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onSdpAnswerFromServer listener " + args[0].toString());
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(args[0].toString());
                        String data = json.getString("sdpAnswer");
                        Constants.userParameters.setSdpAnswer(data);
                        SessionDescription sd = new SessionDescription(SessionDescription.Type.ANSWER,
                                Constants.userParameters.getSdpAnswer());
                        if (userType.equals("presenter")) {
                            nbmWebRTCPeer.processAnswer(sd, "local");
                        } else {
                            nbmWebRTCPeer.processAnswer(sd, "MyRemotePeer");
                        }
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });


        }

        private User setUserFromResponse(JSONObject obj){
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            com.google.gson.JsonParser jsonParser = new com.google.gson.JsonParser();
            JsonObject gsonObject = (JsonObject)jsonParser.parse(obj.toString());
            user = gson.fromJson(gsonObject, User.class);
            Log.i(TAG, "User: " + user.toString());
            Log.i(TAG, "SDPAnswer: " + user.getSdpAnswer());
            Log.i(TAG, "SDPOffer: " + user.getSdpOffer());
            Log.i(TAG, "Response: " + user.getResponse());

            return user;
        }



        @Override
        public void onLocalSdpAnswerGenerated(SessionDescription localSdpAnswer, NBMPeerConnection connection) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onIceCandidate(IceCandidate localIceCandidate, NBMPeerConnection connection) {


            JSONObject cand = new JSONObject();
            try {
                cand.put("candidate", localIceCandidate.sdp);
                cand.put("sdpMid",localIceCandidate.sdpMid);
                cand.put("sdpMLineIndex",Integer.toString(localIceCandidate.sdpMLineIndex));
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            try {
                obj.put("id","onIceCandidate");
                obj.put("candidate",cand);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            Log.i(TAG, "socket check onIce "+ SocketHandler.getmSocket().toString());
            if(SocketHandler.getmSocket().connected()) {
                SocketHandler.getmSocket().emit("OnIceCandidate", obj);
                Log.i(TAG, "Emit IceCandidate succesfull!" + "\n" + localIceCandidate.toString());
                Log.i(TAG, "Emit IceCandidate succesfull!" + "\n" + obj);
            } else {
                Log.i(TAG, "Socket not connected!");
                SocketHandler.getmSocket().connect();
                SocketHandler.getmSocket().emit("OnIceCandidate", obj);
            }

            SocketHandler.getmSocket().on("iceCandidate-mobile", new Emitter.Listener() {
                @Override
                public void call(final Object... args) {
                    Log.i(TAG, "onIceCandidate listener " + args[0]);
                    JSONObject obj = null;
                    try {
                        Log.i(TAG, "onIceCandidate listener " + args[0].toString());
                        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(args[0].toString());
                        String candidate = json.getJSONObject("candidate").getString("candidate");
                        String sdpMid  = json.getJSONObject("candidate").getString("sdpMid");
                        int sdpMLineIndex = Integer.valueOf(json.getJSONObject("candidate").getString("sdpMLineIndex"));
                        IceCandidate ic = new IceCandidate(sdpMid, sdpMLineIndex,candidate);

                        nbmWebRTCPeer.addRemoteIceCandidate(ic, "local");
                   } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                        Log.e(TAG, e.getMessage());
                    }
                }
            });




        }

        @Override
        public void onIceStatusChanged(PeerConnection.IceConnectionState state, NBMPeerConnection connection) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoteStreamAdded(MediaStream stream, NBMPeerConnection connection) {

            nbmWebRTCPeer.attachRendererToRemoteStream(remoteRenderer, stream);

        }

        @Override
        public void onRemoteStreamRemoved(MediaStream stream, NBMPeerConnection connection) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onPeerConnectionError(String error) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onDataChannel(DataChannel dataChannel, NBMPeerConnection connection) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onBufferedAmountChange(long l, NBMPeerConnection connection, DataChannel channel) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onStateChange(NBMPeerConnection connection, DataChannel channel) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onMessage(DataChannel.Buffer buffer, NBMPeerConnection connection, DataChannel channel) {

        }

        private Emitter.Listener onCreateMessage = new Emitter.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void call(final Object... args) {
                Log.i(TAG, "Inside call");
                System.out.println("Room was created by:"+ user.getName());
                presenter();
                runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        if (!SocketHandler.getmSocket().connected()) {
                            SocketHandler.getmSocket().connect();
                        }
                        Log.i(TAG, "Message received");
                        String data = (String) args[0];
                        mData = data;
                        Log.i(TAG, data);
                        Log.i(TAG, new Gson().toJson(data));
                    }
                });
            }
        };

`
```

**Activity Layout**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_video_peer"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="ro.hpm.hypertalk.VideoPeer">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:background="@color/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:weightSum="3"
        android:orientation="horizontal">
        <ImageButton
            android:src="@drawable/video_call_btn1"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:id="@+id/video_call"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/chat"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/chat_btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1" />
        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/contacts"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:scaleType="centerInside"
            android:src="@drawable/contact_list_btn1"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"/>
    </LinearLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_above="@id/footer"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">


        <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
            android:id="@+id/remote_renderer"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true" />

        <org.webrtc.SurfaceViewRenderer
            android:id="@+id/local_renderer"
            android:layout_width="100dp"
            android:layout_height="150dp"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="false"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="false"
            android:layout_alignBottom="@id/remote_renderer"
            android:layout_alignRight="@id/remote_renderer"/>

        <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
            android:id="@+id/container"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"/>
    </RelativeLayout>



</RelativeLayout>
```

I can't figure out why on some devices the code works and on others it doesn't. I used the following permissions in the Manifest file:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_SECURE_VIDEO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAPTURE_AUDIO_OUTPUT" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS" />
```

This is what Android Monitor shows:

```
12-12 12:11:46.261 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 64 for video/avc
12-12 12:11:46.263 10881-12624/? I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 16384 for video/mp4v-es
12-12 12:11:46.263 10881-12624/? I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 16384 for video/mp4v-es
12-12 12:11:46.269 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-pn-realvideo
12-12 12:11:46.271 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/mpeg
12-12 12:11:46.273 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/0 for video/mpeg2
12-12 12:11:46.273 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/2 for video/mpeg2
12-12 12:11:46.273 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
12-12 12:11:46.275 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 32768/2 for video/mp4v-es
12-12 12:11:46.281 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/vc1
12-12 12:11:46.287 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported mime video/x-flv
12-12 12:11:46.291 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/0 for video/mpeg2
12-12 12:11:46.291 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/2 for video/mpeg2
12-12 12:11:46.291 10881-12624/? W/VideoCapabilities: Unrecognized profile/level 0/3 for video/mpeg2
12-12 12:11:46.307 10881-12624/? I/VideoCapabilities: Unsupported profile 4 for video/mp4v-es
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Trying to find HW decoder for mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp8
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.IMG.MSVDX.Decoder.VP8
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.google.vp8.decoder
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: No HW decoder found for mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp8
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Trying to find HW decoder for mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.google.vp9.decoder
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: No HW decoder found for mime video/x-vnd.on2.vp9
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Trying to find HW decoder for mime video/avc
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.IMG.MSVDX.Decoder.AVC
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder: Found candidate decoder OMX.google.h264.decoder
12-12 12:11:46.312 10881-12624/? I/org.webrtc.Logging: MediaCodecVideoDecoder:
```

Comment: Does the Android Monitor display the same issues about not finding the HW decoders for vp8 and vp9 on the Samsung S7 ?

Answer (score 0):

After gathering more details about the issue inside the comments, I can notice that the `MediaCodecVideoDecoder` cannot find a hardware decoder to decode VP8 and VP9 video codecs on the Huawei P9 Lite. It makes sense since these codecs aren't supported on this phone.

You should try disabling the hardware acceleration it inside the `PeerConnectionFactory.initializeAndroidGlobals` call by setting the fourth parameter to false.

Answer (score 0):

In case of this problem, please check the camera format supported by the tester. The CameraEnumerationAndroid class under libjingle_peerconnection.jar provides an API to get the camera format, then compare the camera parameters you set, where the width and height are the same, and the frameRate is smaller than the system supports. Example: new NBMVideoFormat(640, 480, pixelform. RGB_888, 30);